# Rate limit notifications from an app

Tags: applications, notifications, do-not-disturb

So when family and friends go bananas on a communication app, the phone spews alerts endlessly, one for every single message. Sometimes even every time someone starts typing! Some apps, like signal, provide an option to disable alerts for an hour or some other choice of duration. But not all apps have this, and I certainly don't want to disable all notifications.

Is there some way in android to rate limit notifications per app? I will live very happily the rest of my life if Snapchat can send maximum one audio/vibration notification every 10 minutes. Can I make android fix this for me, or is it up to every single app developer to implement this?

I already block and disable some notifications, and I've already set up "Do not disturb". I've never seen any option to avoid these notification torrents, though.